# How to bold specific text using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I use Google Spreadsheets' built-in form functionality to build contact forms on my website.

Now, consider this code:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e)
{

  var email = "team@example.com";

  subject = e.namedValues["Subject"].toString();

  message = "Time: " + e.namedValues["Timestamp"].toString() + "\n\n"
  + "Name: " + e.namedValues["Name"].toString() + "\n\n"
  + "Email: " + e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString() + "\n\n"
  + "Website: " + e.namedValues["Website"].toString() + "\n\n"
  + "Reason For Contacting?: " + e.namedValues["Reason For Contacting?"].toString() + "\n\n"
  + "Message: " + e.namedValues["Message"].toString() + "\n\n";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

}
```

It makes sure that I receive an email as soon as someone submits the form, the email's body has info. like this (example):

> Time: 2012/02/25 11:53
>
> Name: John Davis
>
> Email: John@google.com
>
> Website: http://google.com
>
> Reason For Contacting?: Just wanted to chat with ya
>
> Message: It's been long. Catch me tonight.

So, now you should have a clear idea as to what the code does. The thing is, I want the output to look like this instead (i.e., bold some text):

> **Time:** 2012/02/25 11:53
>
> **Name:** John Davis
>
> **Email:** John@google.com
>
> **Website:** http://google.com
>
> **Reason For Contacting?:** Just wanted to chat with ya
>
> **Message:** It's been long. Catch me tonight.

How do I modify the code to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MailApp.sendEmail can take htmlBody as advancedArgs. Descripted in here http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_mailapp.html

You can send htmlBody like

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
    var email = "team@example.com";
    var subject = e.namedValues["Subject"].toString();
    var msgHtml = "<b>Time</b>: " + e.namedValues["Timestamp"].toString() + "<br/>"
        + "<b>Name:</b> " + e.namedValues["Name"].toString() + "<br/>"
        + "<b>Email:</b> " + e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString() + "<br/>"
        + "<b>Website:</b> " + e.namedValues["Website"].toString() + "<br/>"
        + "<b>Reason For Contacting?:</b> " + e.namedValues["Reason For Contacting?"].toString() + "<br/>"
        + "<b>Message:</b> " + e.namedValues["Message"].toString() + "<br/>";

    var msgPlain = msgHtml.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); // clear html tags and convert br to new lines for plain mail
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msgPlain, { htmlBody: msgHtml });
}
```

The above one's for linebreaks. Use this to separate them by paragraphs:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
    var email = "team@example.com";
    var subject = e.namedValues["Subject"].toString();
    var msgHtml = "<p>" + "<b>Time</b>: " + e.namedValues["Timestamp"].toString() + "</p>"
        + "<p>" + "<b>Name:</b> " + e.namedValues["Name"].toString() + "</p>"
        + "<p>" + "<b>Email:</b> " + e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString() + "</p>"
        + "<p>" + "<b>Website:</b> " + e.namedValues["Website"].toString() + "</p>"
        + "<p>" + "<b>Reason For Contacting?:</b> " + e.namedValues["Reason For Contacting?"].toString() + "</p>"
        + "<p>" + "<b>Message:</b> " + e.namedValues["Message"].toString() + "</p>";

    var msgPlain = msgHtml.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); // clear html tags for plain mail
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msgPlain, { htmlBody: msgHtml });
}
```

I didnt try but it should work.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript or Google Apps Script. Can you please edit the code in my question? Thanks. (I am trying though.)

Comment: It almost worked. But there are no line breaks!! Can you please check once?

Comment: Thanks a lot @arunes. You saved my day! (Just wanted to let you know that I edited your answer a bit with more info, so that it'll be a good reference to noobs like me. Hope you don't mind.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way that worked for me.

```
 function inlineImage() { 
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "Your@email.com",
     subject: "Subject",
     htmlBody: '<a href="http://google.com"> <b>Google</b></a> ' ,

   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442375/how-to-bold-specific-text-using-google-apps-script/47508889#47508889) that [Abe.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7922230/abe-s) provided is simpler.  I combined it with part of [arunes'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225270/arunes) [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442375/how-to-bold-specific-text-using-google-apps-script/9442420#9442420). It's now written in the way [its_me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071413/its-me) requested in their comment to [arunes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225270/arunes):

```
function inlineImage() { 
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "team@example.com",
     subject: e.namedValues["Subject"].toString(),
     htmlBody: "<b>Time</b>: " + e.namedValues["Timestamp"].toString() + "<br/>"
    + "<b>Name:</b> " + e.namedValues["Name"].toString() + "<br/>"
    + "<b>Email:</b> " + e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString() + "<br/>"
    + "<b>Website:</b> " + e.namedValues["Website"].toString() + "<br/>"
    + "<b>Reason For Contacting?:</b> " + e.namedValues["Reason For Contacting?"].toString() + "<br/>"
    + "<b>Message:</b> " + e.namedValues["Message"].toString() + "<br/>",
   });
 }
```

I tested it with my own variables in place of all the "e.namedValues[..." for my application and it worked.  I'm still a novice, so I'm not sure why doing the "msgPlain" to "msgHtml" replacement step would be better.

By the way, I tried to write this as a comment, but I don't have enough points.  Though I guess what I wrote is technically the answer that [its_me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071413/its-me) was looking for originally.  **Many thanks to both [Abe.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7922230/abe-s) and [arunes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225270/arunes) for teaching me about both scripts.**