# How can I set bold text in Google App Script via a Form Submit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The code below generates an email when a form is submitted and presents the data in a legible format. For example:

Name of User ::

Type of Access ::

Email ::

What I would like to have is the headers or the [i] to be in bold. I'm not to familiar with the app script language and have researched how to set bold text, but because this is looping through a list I haven't found an easy way to do so. I have looked at the text docs also. I found this post, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442375/how-to-bold-specific-text-using-google-apps-script) however the answer isn't clear to me.

```
var email = sample@google.com;

var subject_1 = "Network/Computer Access Form"; 


var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
var message = "";    



for(var i in headers) {
message += headers[i] + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 
}

message += "Sheet URL :: " + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl() + "\n";


MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject_1, message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer you refer to you have to use the HTML option, here is how it goes to build both versions in the same loop so you keep compatibility for people allergic to html formatted emails ;-)

```
function sendEmail(e){
  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  var subject_1 = "Network/Computer Access Form"; 
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var messageTxt = "";    
  var messageHTML = "";
  for(var i=0 ; i<headers.length;++i) {
    messageTxt += headers[i] + " :: "+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 
    messageHTML += "<b>"+headers[i] + "</b> :: "+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "<br><br>"; 
  }
  Logger.log(messageHTML);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject_1, messageTxt,{'htmlBody':messageHTML});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an error though, "{ missing from compound statement" on the last line of code. I have no clue where to put it :)

Comment: You have to wrap these lines in a function, I'll edit my answer - I tested and it works.

Comment: Thanks Serge. THis is what I have now, I'm not getting the error anymore, but I'm not getting the email either. I'm sure its something syntactically wrong I'm doing. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61698591/email_001.png

Comment: I guess you have another issue... please try in a new script in a new sheet. Or delete all the code but the mailapp.send..... line with a dummy subject and content to church the email gets sent. As I said, this exact code works for me .

Comment: It worked! I had some other junk in there. Thanks so much Serge, you rock.