# How to format string and number in google script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send mail to a list of people with some important data that i need to be in the e-mail formatted as bold. I tried to use the string.setBold() but it says that the function does not exist. By the way the email is something like this:

```
var emailBody = "¡Hola " + name + "!" +
                "\n\nTe informamos que tienen un pago pendiente por " +
                acobrar + " con el equipo " + equipo + " en Liga Siete" +
                ". Segun nuestros registros han realizado los siguientes pagos" +
                pagos + "\n\nTe recordamos que con la tarifa " + tarifa +
                " deben cancelar un total de " + apagar +
                " y que la garantía no se considera como abono. Recuerda que esta cuota debe ser pagada antes del " +
                deadline +
                " o quedaran inhabilitados de jugar o incluso perder el cupo."
```

Where the variable name, equipo, tarifa and apagar must be in bold.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried simply: `... el equipo <strong>" + equipo + "</strong> en Liga Siete ...`?

Comment: Yep ! And it didnt work out :(

Comment: Do you use the version of `GmailApp.sendEmail` with 4 parameters?  If so, do you set the "htmlBody" option?  Can you show that line of code?

Comment: I found this link which looks to address your problem. [Using bold in gmail]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442375/how-to-bold-specific-text-using-google-apps-script

Comment: @Panda_Claus good find, this question is actually a dupe of that question.  Voting to close.

Comment: @fvu This is how i call it
            MailApp.sendEmail(toAddress, subject, emailBody, {
                name: "xxxx",
                replyTo: "xxx@xxx.com"
            });

Comment: @Panda_Claus im gonna try that ! Thank you ;)