# Apply Underlining, Bold, Italics etc. on email body created in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Can I know how do I insert bolding, underlining, italics, changing of word fonts for email bodies in Google Script? Here is my example, it is an email, I would like to insert various font size, bolding, underlining, adding links etc.

`  function sendEmails(e){

```
 var UserName = e.values[3];

 var UserEmail = e.values[5];

 var date = e.values[0];

 var pin = e.values[4];

 var subject = "[LFR] Application Succeed!";

 var bodymessage = "Hi " + UserName + 

 "\n\n\n\nThank you for sending in your job application on " + date +
 "\n\nThe following is your Purchase Log Pin:\n" + pin +
 "\n\n\n\nBest Regards" +
 "\nLeoFresh Resorts OOA Team\n" +
  subject.strike();
MailApp.sendEmail(UserEmail, subject, bodymessage); }
```

`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442375/how-to-bold-specific-text-using-google-apps-script Basically use HTMLBody option.

Comment: What about underline?

Answer (score 0):

If using HTMLBody then you can add underline to the email by adding a custom css style to the text to be underlined. e.g.

```
some random text <span style="text-decoration: underline">underlined text</span> back to normal
```

text-decoration has the following valid values.

```
underline
line-through
overline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlBody option when sending an email:

```
message += "<br>Here is an <span style="text-decoration: underline;font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;"> Underlined,bold and italic</span>text.";


  GmailApp.sendEmail(sendTo, subject, textbody, {htmlBody: message});
```

`htmlBody` if set, devices capable of rendering HTML will use it instead of the required body argument (here textbody); you can add an optional inlineImages field in HTML body if you have inlined images for your email.

Refer:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options