# bold & italic message in GmailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9uU_KwGgzQ&t=1154s

I have program using the YouTube link that uses Google Form to google sheet then PDF using a template.

But in the GMailApp script, I am unable to bold and underline.

This was the message

```
var message =  
`\nThank you. You have successfully completed your form. 
\nPlease print the attached PDF copy of the form and submit the signed hardcopy by Friday, 16th April 2021. 
\nNote: This is an automated system generated email. Please do not reply this email.`
```

How to bold "**Friday, 16th April 2021**" and
Italic "*Note: This is an automated system generated email. Please do not reply this email.*?

Comment: please edit your question include [example]

Comment: You can use HTML like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243078/apply-underlining-bold-italics-etc-on-email-body-created-in-google-script

Answer (score 2):

```
Use html to build the message variable then pass it to the Gmail app...

var message = '<br>Thank you. You have successfully completed your form.<br>'
   message += 'Please print the attached PDF copy of the form and submit the signed hardcopy by '
   message += '<b><i>Friday, 16th April 2021.</i></b>'
   message += '<br>Note: This is an automated system generated email. Please do not reply this email.'

GmailApp.sendEmail('to@email.address', 'subject', 'message preview',{
      from: from@email.address,
      htmlBody: message
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Format the body with HTML and use the [htmlBody](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) option to send it.