# Is there a way to make part of a cell bold?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have several rows in google sheets that take sentences from several tabs then return them in another tab. Note that those cells contain formulas. I wrote a script and it works perfectly but I don't know what to add to make certain words **BOLD**.

```
     function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Hide')
      .addItem('Hide All Empty Rows', 'clear')
      .addToUi();
}

function clear() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NY Quote with Rebate');
    const sheetRANGE = sheet.getDataRange();
    const rangeVals = sheetRANGE.getValues();

    for (let i = rangeVals.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i > 8) {
            const $row = rangeVals[i];
            let data = 0;
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries($row)) {
                if (value !== '') {
                    data = 1;
                }
            }
            if (data === 0) {
                sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if (maxRows !== lastRow) {
        if (lastRow > 9) {
            sheet.hideRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
        } else {
            sheet.hideRows(9, maxRows - 9);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bold specific text using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442375/how-to-bold-specific-text-using-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value). There's a relevant example in the [`setRichTextValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue) method.

```
// Sets all cells in range B2:D4 to have the text "Hello world", with "Hello" bolded.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");
var bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setBold(true)
    .build();
var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText("Hello world")
    .setTextStyle(0, 5, bold)
    .build();
range.setRichTextValue(richText);
```